# command npm generates errors related to lifecycle and starting the App

Tags: javascript, npm, openlayers, npm-install, npm-start

i am learning openlayers and javascript. in the followig tutorial

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html

it shows a simple openlayers project with javascript. i follow the tutorial but the command

```
npm start 
npm run start
```

gives me the following error:

```
    (venv) M:\openlayers\projects\app1>npm start

> app1@1.0.0 start M:\openlayers\projects\app1
> parcel index.html

Der Befehl "parcel" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app1@1.0.0 start: `parcel index.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the app1@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Amr.Bakri\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-17T09_48_09_536Z-debug.log
```

**index.javascript**:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import {Map, View} from 'ol';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
  })
});
```

**index.html**:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Using Parcel with OpenLayers</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 400px;
        height: 250px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the right command is `npm run start`, it's a misspelling, if you continue you can find the build command is `npm run build`

Comment: i used npm run start but i receive the same error

Comment: I tried to follow the same guidelines and it works for me, at https://github.com/macorifice/parcel-project the example project, I've added the engines inside the package.json, maybe it's an npm or node version issue

Comment: If any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. If there's still anything unclear in an answer, don't hesitate to ask.